# Error during pipeline execution: Cannot get host IP: cannot get node: node billingtransactionsprod-o-06150305-c2d7-harness-0 not found

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

During a pipeline execution, we're obtaining the below errors:

```
12:18:03.000 E0615 10:18:03.739861 2591 kubelet.go:1534] error getting node: node billingtransactionsprod-o-06150305-c2d7-harness-0 not found
E0615 10:18:03.739861    2591 kubelet.go:1534] error getting node: node billingtransactionsprod-o-06150305-c2d7-harness-0 not found

12:18:04.000 E0615 10:18:04.014702 2591 kubelet.go:1958] Cannot get host IP: cannot get node: node billingtransactionsprod-o-06150305-c2d7-harness-0 not found
E0615 10:18:04.014702    2591 kubelet.go:1958] Cannot get host IP: cannot get node: node billingtransactionsprod-o-06150305-c2d7-harness-0 not found
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors have no impact on the running of your job. The error message here indicates that the node failed to register itself to the Kubernetes apiserver. Dataflow however uses a ContainerVM and thus has no apiserver.